# Completion of the local ring at a point on arithmetic surfaces.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, power-series, surfaces, local-rings

Let $K$ be a number field and consider a arithmetic surface $X\to B=\operatorname{Spec} O_K$, i.e. $X$ is integral, **regular**, flat, proper over $O_K$ and it has dimension $2$.

Now pick a closed point $x\in X$ such that $x\mapsto b\in B$ and consider $\widehat{\mathcal O_{X,x}}$. In other words the completion of the local ring $\mathcal O_{X,x}$ with respect to its maximal ideal.

> Can we express $\widehat{\mathcal O_{X,x}}= A[[t]]$? What is $A$ in
>   this case?  Do we have $A=O_L$ where $L$ is a complete discrete
>   valuation field and a finite extension of $K_b$ (here $K_b$ is the completion of $K$ at $b$)?

For sure we have an embedding  $\mathcal O_{B,b}[t]\hookrightarrow\mathcal 
 O_{X,x}$

Thanks in advance

Comment: I asked a similar question in Mathoverflow some time ago but I didn't get an answer:  [Completion of a local ring of an arithmetic surface](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/319169/completion-of-a-local-ring-of-an-arithmetic-surface)

Comment: Take a look at Liu's book exercise 4, 3.35 (d) at page 149. But it assumes the existence of a section.